# RadioButtonFor in mvc shows required validation even though not applied required validation

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I have one view in which I put two radio button for attribute in my model 
I just put data annotation for other field but not the radiobutonfor field but steel it show required validation.Below is my code.I the attribute is int type in model.I used javascript unobtrusive library inn view as well.

```
 <td>
   <label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.OneToOne, 1) Hours </label>
   <label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.OneToOne, 2) Unit </label>
  </td>
```

I am using Html.begin from to post this value.

Comment: its because in your model, an int cannot be null. use nullable<int>, int?, or give it a default value to make it not break your model state.

Answer (score 0):

The `RadioButtonFor` helper method generates html markup for the radio button input with `data-val-required` attribute unless you specify the property as nullable type! The jQuery validate plugin does validation on this input because of the existence of this attribute.

If you do not want client side validation on this input, You should change the property type from `int` to nullable int(`int?`).

```
 public class YourViewModel
 {
    // Other properties
    public int? OneToOne { set; get; }
 }
```

Comment: can we restrict  RadioButtonFor to not include data-val-required ?

Answer (score 0):

If radio buttons are not required to select, I *personally* like to use ***mutually exclusive checkboxes***.

Mainly, if a user accidental selects a radio button, s/he won't be able to uncheck it back unless the user refreshes the entire page. I feel like it is really annoying.

***Sample at [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/7rk7rjh5/)***

### Model

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public bool OneToOneHours { get; set; }
    public bool OneToOneUnit { get; set; }
}
```

### View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", null, FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="form-control">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.OneToOneHours, new {@class = "mutually-exclusive"}) Hours
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.OneToOneUnit, new {@class = "mutually-exclusive"}) Unit
    </div>
    <button id="btnSubmit" type="submit">Submit</button>
}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

    $('input.mutually-exclusive').click(function () {
        var checkedState = $(this).val();;
        $('input.mutually-exclusive').attr("checked", false);
        $(this).prop("checked", checkedState);
    });

</script>
```

### Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(ViewModel model)
    {
        int? oneToOne;
        if (model.OneToOneHours)
            oneToOne = 1;
        else if (model.OneToOneUnit)
            oneToOne = 2;

        return View(model);
    }
}
```